# android support library v 23.3.0 snackbar issue

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-snackbar

When I use support library v 23.2.1 the snackbar moves the fab buttons correctly but after updating the support library to v 23.3.0 the fab buttons go up but doesn't comes down. I am forced to use v 23.2.1.

And the problem is happening only with Marshmallow android version, with jelly bean its working fine for both(v23.3.0 & v23.2.1).

can anybody explain? Please.

Comment: I realized this today too, Probably google stopped testing their releases at some-point. :(

Comment: Google stopped testing??... No yaar.... Please don't scare me.

Comment: I'm just pissed off, they probably test but they probably don't care about Devices other than Nexus :(

Comment: I am using nexus device only . still the issue persists.

Comment: Have you filed a bug report? I have the same issue.

Comment: @gbhall It doesn't happen all the time.. mostly when running app via instant run. A fresh and full build install removes this error for me. I think its something to do with instant runs as I am using android studio 2.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested the library in 3 apps that i'm working on, i do not have issues with snackbar, it could be that is the wrong view to show the snackbar, i think you have to call in the CoordinatorLayout.

`View mViewCoordinatorLayout = findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout);
 if(mViewCoordinatorLayout != null){
 Snackbar.make(mViewCoordinatorLayout, R.string.someString , Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
    }`

Comment: no bro, still not working... tried your coordinator layout method also... it works on older android versions like JB but not on android M.

Comment: hi, sorry to hear that, my best guess would be the way that your layout it's "build" i once have that problem, in the link is an app that i made specifically to be used has a template for other apps, it has the correct layout, listeners , the drawer , snack bars and fragments, check it out, the layouts are in " app/src/main/res/layout/ ".

  [link](https://github.com/LuisEvilCo/TemplateApplication)